# How to add a momentary value to a sql query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this query in Laravel 8:

```
$articles = Article::whereIn('category_id', $categories)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query2) {
            $query2->where('draft', 0)->whereNull('publication_date');
        })->orWhere(function ($query2) {
            $query2->where('draft', 0)->where('publication_date', '<=', DateHelper::currentDateTime());
        });
    })->orderBy('publicated_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

I need to add a momentary id to this query named desc_id, so that the values $articles that i query have a desc_id based on the publication_date.
The result that i need to achieve is like this:

| id | name | category | publication_date | desc_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | bananas | news | 2022-01-16 17:30:00 | 1 |
| 27 | kiwis | news | 2021-12-05 21:30:00 | 3 |
| 50 | apples | news | 2022-01-07 09:14:00 | 2 |

I've tried adding it by passing all the elements of $articles into an empty array adding a value:

```
$count =0;
$allArticles = [];

foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $count++;
    $allArticles[] = $article->with('desc_id', $count);
}
```

I know that my method is incorrect but i hope that it helps understanding my question.

Comment: You dont need to add an index to the results since the array has already an index. When you loop, you can do it like this `foreach ($articles as $index => $article) {` and use the `$index` variable (that starts from 0 ) (did not down vote btw and it would help us help you if you explained why you need that index in the results)

Comment: i need this to paginate the articles depending on their row number from the query, because i have to create a html page for every 8 articles that the query gives me

Comment: You can still use the array index for that. Or better do the pagination in the DB query and not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to have the line number of each row which can be achieve like this :

```
Article::whereIn(...)->select()
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('RANK() OVER(ORDER BY publicated_at DESC) as desc_id'))
    ->orderBy('publicated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```